# Webcam and fingerprint reader not found on Lenovo X200 with Debian

Tags: debian, thinkpad, webcam, fingerprint

I installed Debian 7.6 Wheezy on a Lenovo X200. Most of the modules worked out of the box and I only had to manually supply the WiFi drivers.

However the built-in webcam was not found and can't be used. The fingerprint reader of the laptop was also not found.

How can I get them working?